# Is my IMU using ENU convention? (for robot_localization)

Tags: ros, navigation, gps, robot-localization, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm using a Razor IMU from Sparkfun and it is the old model SEN-10736 which is compatible with ROS.
I followed all the steps reported on [razor_imu_9dof](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof) tutorial in order to upload the new firmware and make the IMU work with the `razor_imu_9dof` ROS driver.

Since I need to use it with `robot_localization` package, for [GPS integration](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html), I would like to know if my IMU heading data start with zero point facing east or not as suggested on the robot_localization tutorial:

> Since version 2.2.1,
> navsat_transform_node has moved to a
> standard wherein all heading data is
> assumed to start with its zero point
> facing east. If your IMU does not
> conform to this standard and instead
> reports zero when facing north, you
> can still use the yaw_offset parameter
> to correct this. In this case, the
> value for yaw_offset would be π/2
> (approximately 1.5707963).

How can I know if my IMU is already using the correct orientation or not?
I took two pictures when facing EAST and when facing NORTH.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

So, I think my IMU reports 0 when facing NORTH.
In this case, should I use:

```
 <param name="yaw_offset" value="1.5707963"/>
```

in my launch file in order to make the IMU outputs 0 when it faces EAST?
Is it correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256122/is-my-imu-using-enu-convention?-(for-robot_localization)/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, see the section on IMU data [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html#imu).

Your IMU does appear to have the correct sign, at least for yaw. You are correct that you need the 90-degree offset you have specified. However, you should check what the magnetic declination is for your location as well, and make sure to set that parameter.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0